# No route matches [GET] "/packs/application.js" Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

When running integration specs on Rails 5.1 the javascript_pack_tag helper generates a path for the compiled packs/application.js file in `public/packs/application.js`

However, `bin/rails assets:precompile` will compile your packs with the production configuration, which includes digesting. Thus the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compile packs/application.js into `public/packs/application.js` specify the development environment via:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/webpack
```

Run this task before running your integration specs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my setup to run webpack-dev-server in a local test environment when using the Rails 5.1 webpacker gem:

In `config/environments/test.rb`, add:

```rb
unless ENV['CI'] == 'true'
  config.x.webpacker[:dev_server_host] = "http://localhost:8080"
end
```

Then in `spec/rails_helper.rb` or your test setup, add:

```
config.add_setting :webpack_dev_server_pid

config.before(:suite) do
  unless ENV['CI'] == 'true'
    RSpec.configuration.webpack_dev_server_pid = fork do
      puts "Child process starting webpack-dev-server"
      webpack_dev_server_cmd = [
        "#{Rails.root}/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
        "--config #{Rails.root}/config/webpack/development.js",
        "--content-base #{Rails.root}/public/packs",
        "--quiet"
      ].join(" ")
      exec(webpack_dev_server_cmd)
    end
  end
end

config.after(:suite) do
  unless ENV['CI'] == 'true'
    puts "Killing webpack-dev-server"
    Process.kill("HUP",RSpec.configuration.webpack_dev_server_pid)
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(2) do
        Process.wait(RSpec.configuration.webpack_dev_server_pid,0)
      end
    rescue => Timeout::Error
      Process.kill(9,RSpec.configuration.webpack_dev_server_pid)
    ensure
      RSpec.configuration.webpack_dev_server_pid = nil
    end
  end
end
```

This setup allows you to set `CI=true` in a continuous integration environment to disable the webpack-dev-server, where instead you can run `RAILS_ENV=development bin/webpack` before executing your test suite.

Credit to this Github [comment](https://github.com/mipearson/webpack-rails/issues/26#issuecomment-236963272).

Answer (score 0):

This is my list of local build commands to support all Rails 5.1 updates:

```
brew update 
brew install yarn 
./bin/yarn install 
./bin/yarn add webpack 
./bin/webpack-watcher 
bundle exec rake db:create 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```